# how to search file for begin of string and save a variable

Tags: linux, bash, files, search

i am trying to find a way of searching a file for string,
it needs to work by searching then file and if any line in the file begin with what i am searching for, then take that whole line and save it as variable so i can using it later on kick off another command.

i have try this in python but i want to find a way in bash

```
def f(inputpara,substringpara):
   temp_log=""
   for item in inputpara.split("\n"):
    if  substringpara in item :
             temp_log=item.strip()
  return  temp_log
```

thanks i was able to get it working

```
IFS=$'\n' lines=( $(grep 'string*' textout.txt) )

    for i in "{lines[@]}"
            do
             echo ${lines[@]}
    done
```

Comment: Perhaps `man grep`?

Comment: Do you want only the first matching line?  An array containing all of them?  Any, ie. don't care which?

Comment: well in the text file there are only 10 line and the lines that i want to pull out are all unique, so it should work with the first matching line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` to find the string at the start of the line and an array to save the results:

```
IFS=$'\n' lines=( $(grep '^string' file.txt) )
```

- `grep '^string' file.txt` finds the string `string` at the start of lines of file `file.txt`
- The array `lines` contains the matched lines, the `IFS=$'\n'` makes each line an array element

Now you can iterate over the results using regular array operations.

For example, to find the number of lines found:

```
${#lines[@]}
```

First element:

```
${lines[0]}
```

Second element:

```
${lines[1]}
```

Iterate over the elements using `for` loop:

```
for i in "{lines[@]}"; do ....; done
```